# CosmosClient : Custom json converter works out of the box with NewtonSoft, not with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, system.text.json, cosmosclient

**Scenario :**

- I have a cosmosDb container stored in Azure.
- I have this kind of data class that I read and write to it :

  ```
  public class MyClass {
       public Guid Id { get; private set; }
       public string PartitionKey { get; private set; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeJsonConverter))]
       //[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeNewtonsoftJsonConverter))]
       public MyType Custom { get; private set; }

       [JsonConstructor] // <-- I've tried with and without this
       public MyClass(Guid id, string pk, MyType custom) {
            Custom = custom; Id = id; PartitionKey = pk;
       }
  }
  ```
- as you can see there's **a custom type, MyType**, that gets converted with a **custom converter.**
- For test purposes, I wrote the converter both with Newtonsoft and System.Text:

  ```
  public class MyTypeJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyType> {

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { ... }
       public override void Write(...) { ... } 
       public override Context Read(...) { ... } 
  }

  public class ContextNewtonsoftJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter {

       ... 
  }
  ```
- I know that **MyType works** and that **the converters work** because serialization and deserialization work as expected both with System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json when I do just this :

  ```
    Newtonsoft
    //var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(someJson);

    //System.Text.Json
    var myClass2 =
       JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(someJson,
          new JsonSerializerOptions()
             { IgnoreNullValues = false, PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });
  ```
- A similar deserialization happens too when I read and write objects from CosmosDb.

  ```
       CosmosClientOptions options = new()
       {
             ConnectionMode = DebugHelper.DebugMode ? 
                   ConnectionMode.Gateway : ConnectionMode.Direct,
             SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions
             {
             IgnoreNullValues = false,
             PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
             },
       };
       var cosmosClient = CosmosClient
                   .CreateAndInitializeAsync(connectionString, 
                         containersList, options)
                   .GetAwaiter()
                   .GetResult();

       var container = cosmosClient .GetContainer("mydatabase", "mycontainer");


       var items = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyType>(allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true);
       foreach (var item in items)
       {
             await container.DeleteItemAsync<MyType>(item.Id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(item.PartitionKey));
       }
  ```

**Problem :**

**the code just above works perfectly with the NewtonSoft version...
...But fails with the System.Text.Json version.**

> ---- Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Error converting value "my string value" to type
> 'MyType'.
> -------- System.ArgumentException : Could not cast or convert from System.String to MyType.

That exception does NOT happen **inside** the `Read` and `Write` functons of the converter. It happens "beforehand".  It's like the `[JsonConverter(...)]` attribute is understood by `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Mytype>` but not by `cosmosContainer.DoSomethingWithItem<MyType>` .

**Again; it works with a plain serialization/desrialization,** and it works with the CosmosClient when I use Newtonsoft.

**Question :**

- (before you dive into complex Json) Can you spot an **obvious** mistake?
- Do I need to **register** the custom JsonConverter, and if yes what's the **most compact way** of doing that? (Anything that doesn't require me to implement **an entire custom Serializer** to pass to CosmosDb... unless you can prove to me that there's a good explanation why Newtonsoft can do it without it but System.Text.Json can't)

Comment: adding an implicit operator fixes the issue but I feel like it's a dirty hack :   `public static implicit operator Context(string s)  {  return new Context(s);   }` It's somewhat redundant to the Json converter. Or is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and should, in your case) register a custom Serializer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace FooBar
{
    // Custom implementation of CosmosSerializer which works with System.Text.Json instead of Json.NET.
    // https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/202
    // This is temporary, until CosmosDB SDK v4 is available, which should remove the Json.NET dependency.
    public class CosmosNetSerializer : CosmosSerializer
    {
        private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions;

        public CosmosNetSerializer() => this._serializerOptions = null;

        public CosmosNetSerializer(JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions) => this._serializerOptions = serializerOptions;

        public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
                {
                    return (T)(object)stream;
                }

                return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, this._serializerOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }

        public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
        {
            var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

            //TODO: replace with sync variant too?
            JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<T>(outputStream, input, this._serializerOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            outputStream.Position = 0;
            return outputStream;
        }
    }
}
```

```
CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(sysConfig.CosmosEndpointUri, tokenCredential)
  .WithConnectionModeDirect()
// ... With()...
  .WithCustomSerializer(new CosmosNetSerializer(Globals.JsonSerializerOptions))
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/Azure/Mission-Critical-Online/blob/main/src/app/AlwaysOn.Shared/Services/CosmosDbService.cs)

Comment: *sad noises* ... Would you be able to point out where the cosmosclient is configured to use Newtonsoft? I think that's my root problm there : it defaults to Newtonsoft without asking me. Is it only in the client builder or can it be somewhere else?

Comment: In my solution it is configured to use STJ, instead of Newtonsoft (which is the built-in default)

Comment: Oh I only just understood that Json.Net is not a "choice" but a forced implementation until a more recent CosmosDb. ...And here I was, proud of having removed all dependencies to it in my own code.

Comment: Well, if you follow my example, you can switch to STJ...