# Get a result object from Cosmos DB that has an interface as an object member

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

Currently I have a class stored in Cosmos DB. That class has an interface as a member variable. When I try and query for that and iterate over the results I get an exception.

```
public class Group
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "partitionKey")]
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

    public IResult Result;
}
```

And then my code to retrieve those objects.

```
var getAllGroupObjects = $"SELECT *\r\nFROM c\r\nWHERE c.id IN (\"{string.Join("\",\"", currentGroupIds)}\")";

QueryDefinition getAllGroupsQuery = new QueryDefinition(getAllGroupObjects);
FeedIterator<Group> allGroupsSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Group>(getAllGroupsQuery);

List<Group> allGroups = new List<Group>();

while (allGroupsSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var currentResultSet2 = await allGroupsSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (Group l in currentResultSet2)
    {
        allGroups.Add(l);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception from Newtonsoft.Json

```
Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type Shared.Types.IResult. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[1].TotalPoints', line 1, position 3298.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosSerializerCore.FromFeedStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serializer.CosmosElementSerializer.GetResourcesHelper[T](IReadOnlyList`1 cosmosElements, CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore, CosmosSerializationFormatOptions cosmosSerializationOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serializer.CosmosElementSerializer.GetResources[T](IReadOnlyList`1 cosmosArray, CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.QueryResponse`1..ctor(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, IReadOnlyList`1 cosmosElements, CosmosQueryResponseMessageHeaders responseMessageHeaders, CosmosDiagnostics diagnostics, CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore, CosmosSerializationFormatOptions serializationOptions, RequestMessage requestMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.QueryResponse`1.CreateResponse[TInput](QueryResponse cosmosQueryResponse, CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateQueryFeedResponseHelper[T](ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateQueryFeedUserTypeResponse[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.FeedIteratorCore`1.ReadNextAsync(ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult](String containerName, String databaseName, OperationType operationType, ITrace trace, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, String operationName, RequestOptions requestOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`1.<<OperationHelperWithRootTraceWithSynchronizationContextAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

My IResult object is an interface that can be implemented by one of a few types of classes. Is there a way to have CosmosDB not panic when it has this iterator going over these objects that have implemented interfaces?

Comment: So I was able to get the converter described below hooked up, but I was never able to figure out how/where to *actually* do the cast to a different class. Instead, I took a step back and realized I probably wanted to store that object in a separate container in Cosmos, which actually made more sense instead of it all being in a single class. And then I can just query for those class types directly and didn't have the problem anymore. I still might come back to this to figure out because it might be necessary in those cases, but it isn't in my current case anymore.

Comment: Also, one of the points I noticed was that I couldn't seem to get some of the example conversion code working when itw as a nested class situation. So if I had class Group with a member variable that is IResult, it wouldn't do the correct conversions.

But if I had just IResult as the top most class it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a custom JsonConverter:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResultConverter))]
public IResult Result { get; set; }
```

Take a look at this on how to write the JsonConverter:
[CosmosClient : Custom json converter works out of the box with NewtonSoft, not with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219161/cosmosclient-custom-json-converter-works-out-of-the-box-with-newtonsoft-not-w)